# how to make a fork cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, fork, cluster-computing

Sorry for asking trivial questions. I am using 'makeForkCluster' function in Parallel package to create clusters on Linux. But there isn't any response (no error, no warning and success). I would appreciate if if anyone can give some examples.

Here is my code of the function:

```
cl_fork <- makeForkCluster(nnodes = getOption("mc.cores", 2L), useXDR = FALSE,port=11330)
```

Comment: I´m not sure if I understand the question correctly... maybe you are searching for `?clusterApply` or `?clusterCall`

Comment: @holzben  I assume YYY means that the call to `makeForkCluster` never returns, or in other words, it hangs.

Comment: Why did you bother to specify an alternative port?  And do you have any sort of firewall running on this machine?

Comment: @SteveWeston you are correct makeForkCluster never returns. When I use makeCluster method without specifying the port , there is error 'connection cannot be opened'.

Comment: It sounds like you're having trouble creating socket connections which could be due to a firewall.

Comment: @SteveWeston Thank you Steve. The problem has been solved after the firewall changes.